# Entity framework sp_executesql performance issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have the following C# code

```
 selectedJobTypesIds.Each(x => matchingJobTypeIds.AddRange(context.GetDescendantJobTypes(x).Select(y => y.Id)));
```

Which when profiled give the following SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[JobTypeDescendantJobTypes] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[JobTypes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ParentJobTypeId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 bigint',@p__linq__0=1
```

When I run this SQL code in SQL Server Management Studio it takes 8-9 seconds. If I extract the SQL and run it, it returns instantly (see below)

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM  [dbo].[JobTypeDescendantJobTypes] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[JobTypes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE [Extent1].[ParentJobTypeId] = 2
```

Why does the sp_executesql suffer from performance issues and how can I fix this in entity framework?

Comment: You should compare execution plans for both, I suspect parameter sniffing. Second are you sure that your query isn't blocked by other transactions when using EF? Last do you clear buffers/cache when executing both in SSMS, because when you try sp_executesql some data may be cached it is much faster when you execute simple select.

Comment: Thanks @lad2025 here is the execution plan (http://screencast.com/t/m6bzU7LiPg) I can't really see where they differ other than the sp_executesql has a filter to rule out nulls and seems to return a lot more rows on the Concatenate. Can you see anything obvious. I have tried your other suggestions but have found nothing.

Comment: Please share execution plans for entire queries, full screen

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/bwat0679M look in the properties "Actual number of rows" = 775116 for sp_executesql and the select = 2609.

Would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: For test add also `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` between both executions

Comment: Please execute both for the same value `WHERE [Extent1].[ParentJobTypeId] = 2`, in dynamic sql you execute with value `1`

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/Sc7RDy4cZ - sorry, still the same result lad. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Your queries are different, dynamic has ParentJobTypeId 1, normal 2

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/Sc7RDy4cZ - I have changed it and get the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89914/discussion-between-burt-and-lad2025).